# Android studio Testcases were not found after migrating from eclipse

Tags: android, android-studio, android-testing

I switched from eclipse adt to android studio. Now I want to run my testcases which were running in eclipse but in android studio I receive the message

```
Running tests
Test running startedTest running failed: Instrumentation run failed due to    'java.lang.RuntimeException'
Empty test suite.
```

My project structure is like this

```
    +---.gradle
    +---.idea
    +---.settings
    +---assets
    +---bin
    +---build
    +---gen
    +---gradle
    +---keystore
    +---libs
    +---release
    +---res
    +---src
    \---tests
        \---TestPDiXUploaderTest
            +---.settings
            +---assets
            +---bin
            +---gen
            +---libs
            +---res
            \---src
                \---de
                    \---srs
                        \---android
                            \---pdixuploader
                                +---mocks
                                +---services
                                +---test
                                |   \---network
                                \---util
```

Because I read that it is necessary to configure the src path of my TestCases in the gradle file I added this in the build.gradle

```
android {
compileSdkVersion 17
buildToolsVersion "19.1.0"

packagingOptions {
    exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
}

sourceSets {
    main {
        manifest.srcFile 'AndroidManifest.xml'
        java.srcDirs = ['src']
        resources.srcDirs = ['src']
        aidl.srcDirs = ['src']
        renderscript.srcDirs = ['src']
        res.srcDirs = ['res']
        assets.srcDirs = ['assets']
    }

    // Move the tests to tests/java, tests/res, etc...
    instrumentTest.setRoot('tests/TestPDiXUploaderTest/src')
    androidTest.setRoot('tests/TestPDiXUploaderTest/src')

    // Move the build types to build-types/<type>
    // For instance, build-types/debug/java, build-types/debug/AndroidManifest.xml, ...
    // This moves them out of them default location under src/<type>/... which would
    // conflict with src/ being used by the main source set.
    // Adding new build types or product flavors should be accompanied
    // by a similar customization.
    debug.setRoot('build-types/debug')
    release.setRoot('build-types/release')
}
```

Thanks for your advice

Comment: I took the long road and restructured my project so its like a newly created android studio project. With this structure I was able to start my testcases again